# Including bearer token in every request and keeping the user logged

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-session

I have an API running in a certain server, when you send a successful request to the login endpoint, it provides you with a JSONWEBTOKEN. 
On my second server, I'm running a website which is sending the requests to the API. What I want is to save the JWT token the user receives when logging in, and saving it so every next request from the user also sends the Bearer token with them, while keeping the user logged.

I have tried including express-session in the requests, using

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))
```

But I can't find how to exactly use it to do what I need in the documentation.

Comment: This should be handle on your website as you are sending requests from there. You can store the login response and token in local storage, how to add it in every request, that depends on the platform your website is built in. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @MohammedAmirAnsari That's what I'd like to do, my website is running an express server, but I'm confused as to what to do next.

Comment: Do you have two different artifacts web and api or do you have all in one artifact?

Comment: @JRichardsz Different, my API is running on a different server. I want to handle sessions on the server running the website.

Comment: Are you requesting the login endpoint in your backend or with javascript/ajax/form  in your frontend? What language are you using to serve your website? Where is deployed your /login endpoint , in your api or in the server of your website?

Comment: @JRichardsz I thought I literally just answered those. Yes, I am requesting the endpoint to my backend with AJAX from the frontend, my website is running express, meaning it's running NodeJS, my login endpoint is deployed on the API server like I just said in my question.

Answer (score 1):

> Quick Answer

### What I want is to save the JWT token the user receives when logging in, and saving it

In your web server, you create the token. So you could store anywhere (db). This is commonly required when you need a functionality like : revoke tokens or stop any activity of certain user. So you web admin, delete this users and **flag** the email and or token, so when this user performs a new http invocation, system will show "Your are not allowed... "

If you will not have this functionality, dont't store the token in your servers. Just create it and send to the user. Common javascript frameworks, will store this  token some where in the browser like **localstorage** and when an invocation to an api es required, javascript frameworks just get the token from localstorage.

### so every next request from the user also sends the Bearer token with them

If you have a valid token in your frontend, you could use it to every next request to the api.

### while keeping the user logged

That's is another world: detect idle users and expire its sessions is **highly recommended in security** terms.

Any way if you need **keeping the user logged** no matter what, I show you two strategies :

**Increase expiration(not recommend)**

Configure the express expiration and token expiration a long as you can.

**Refresh**

Create an endpoints like /refresh in your web server. This endpoints will be responsible to refresh session in your web express server and refresh your token if is already expire. Finally your web int in the browser with javascript (current frameworks) must hit to his endpoint at intervals. With this your session and token will never expire.

Also this could help to detect an idle user. For example with a javascript you could detect clicks or another events. So in this event call to the /refresh endpoint. An active user will have valid web express session and renewed tokens. An idle user **won't trigger this click event**, so /refresh endpoint is not invoked. When user welcome, performs a click, /refresh endpoint will be invoked and must return flags , indicating that web express session is expired and tokens are expired also.

---

### Externalize your Security Engine

If you have more websites, apis, mobil apps, etc, read this section

Based on how nowadays world class platforms works and if you will have more websites/apis/etc I advice you to use oauth2.

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrichardsz/static_resources/master/oauth/oauth-workflow.png]

You are a bit closer with /login endpoint in your api. Your artifacts will be:

- security server/engine (manages authentication and authorization)
- api
- web

This security engine must have in the most easy way, two endpoints:

### /login

Exchange valid credentials for a token

- Websites, systems or apps **must not implement this logic inside it**. Must consume /login from its web server backend (express) or from javascript in the browser with ajax.
- Generated token must be sent to the web. And web will send it to the apis.

### /validate-token :

This endpoints is responsible to check if token is valid, correct signature, expired, etc

**Apis**, must receive the token and check its validation consuming **/validate-token** endpoint. If is a valid token, api must perform the requested operation like list customers, persist values on the db, etc. If this endpoint returns an error, api will notify to the web this error and web must show an error to the user.

If you have an Api Gateway, configure this endpoints on it, so every call to your api, the api gateway will perform the validation of incoming token.

### Oauth2 need a lot of others endpoints

Oauth2 need a lot of others endpoints and functionalities like: unique form login for all your apps, grant consent flow, refresh token, revoke tokens, user managements, etc

Finally my advice is to develop your own security engine or if you have no time (always) search some oauth2 server or oauth2 provider and use it!

Check these oauth2 documentations or flow samples:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749
- Oauth2 alternatives: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/05/30/openid-oauth-saml/
- https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/map-oauth-2-0-specs/
- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/endpoints.html
- https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2
- https://docs.openstack.org/infra/openstackid/oauth2.html
- https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use
- Easy workflow : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

And check my own oauth2 provider:

- https://github.com/jrichardsz/oauth2-shield